# How can i put a fadein effect in my jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I want to know how can i put the fadeIn code here? i have a gridview inside a gridview and i want to put a effect in it when the user clicks the "plus/minus" picture, as of now my effect is just a simple popup through the gridview, how can i put the fadeIn or slideDown effect into my code?

below is my code

```
$("[src*=plus]").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan ='100%'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
    $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/minus2.png");
});
$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/plus2.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
});
```

Comment: Note: there's no need to edit your question title to say "SOLVED" - just accept the most helpful answer and leave it at that.

Comment: and guys please use `.on` as `.live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide the content initially, allowing you to use `fadeIn()`

```
$("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
    var container = $(this).closest("tr"),
        newContent = $("<tr><td></td><td colspan ='100%'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>").hide();
    container.after(newContent);
    newContent.fadeIn();
    $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/minus2.png");
});

$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/plus2.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: See changes involving `newContent`

Answer (score 3):

If you immediately add display:none to the element you spawn you should be able to fade it in. To fade out, you'll need to use a callback in the fadeOut function for removing the element, that way there's time for it to transition before you drop it. *Revised so the row fades and not the image, based on what you needed

```
$("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
      $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr style='display:none;'><td></td><td colspan ='100%'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
      $("tr[style*='display:none']").fadeIn(500);
      $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/minus2.png");
});

$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
      $(this).attr("src", "../Images/Icons/plus2.png");
      var removedTr = $(this).closest("tr").next();
      removedTr.fadeOut(500, function(){
         removedTr.remove();
      });
});
```

Comment: Oh whoops, I'm sorry, I got my javascript and jquery wires crossed. Updated the snipped above!

Comment: It needed to be .css and not .style, my bad! .style is regular javascript and needs different syntax.

Comment: it works but the image is the one fading in. not gridview inside. lol

Comment: FuriousD's solution works - I didn't realize you were trying to get the tr and not the image, makes sense though. Updated my solution to reflect this.

Comment: Will and FuriousD, thank you! it works! thank you very much! voted as asnwered!